# How to use cerial serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, cereal

I'm trying to figure out how Cereal serialization works, so i read the documentation (which i find a little lacking imo) and tried to reproduce the code they have in there:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <archives/binary.hpp>

struct MyData
{
  int x, y, z;

  // This method lets cereal know which data members to serialize
  template<class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive & archive)
  {
    archive( x, y, z ); // serialize things by passing them to the archive
  }
};

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss; // any stream can be used

     {
       cereal::BinaryOutputArchive oarchive(ss); // Create an output archive

       MyData m1, m2, m3;
       oarchive(m1, m2, m3); // Write the data to the archive
     } // archive goes out of scope, ensuring all contents are flushed

     {
       cereal::BinaryInputArchive iarchive(ss); // Create an input archive

       MyData m1, m2, m3;
       iarchive(m1, m2, m3); // Read the data from the archive
     }

    return 0;
}
```

I copied the code directly from Cereal's documentation, but i keep getting an error saying:

`type 'cereal::BinaryInputArchive' does not provide a call operator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently i wasn't including correctly the libraries, that fixed the problem.